# How to get incremental values of alphabets in a range of a number?

Tags: excel

For example I have number 3.

I want a range that gives me A, B, C.

I can't think of a way to do this in excel even getting the range 1, 2, 3. Thanks.

Comment: so you want the result in separate cells?

Comment: Have you tried anything to share for debugging purposes? Also, your excel version will be relevant to add.

Comment: One cell is what Im looking for but I can just reference it if its in seperate cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SEQUENCE and the dynamic array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,CHAR(SEQUENCE(,A1,65)))
```

This will work till "Z"

[image]

If one needs to go beyond "Z" we can use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,SEQUENCE(A1),4),"1",""))
```

Or as JvdV showed:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",,ADDRESS(1,SEQUENCE(A1),4)),"1","")
```

Which probably will reduce the calculations.

Just note that the use of ADDRESS makes this volatile and it will recompute every time Excel has a change.